# Split PHP code of a module into separated include files

Tags: php, dry, require-once

I have a block of code that I need to use in so many places of my app.

Example:

```
$count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);
$c_devices   = $count_device['Count_of_devices'];
$c_active    = $count_device['Count_of_active'];
$c_inactive  = $count_device['Count_of_inactive'];
$c_offline   = $count_device['Count_of_offline'];
```

---

Right now, they in are `10` of my controllers.
If I need to fix anything, I need to fix in `10` places.

I'm seeking a better way to control this.

---

I thought of writing a function

```
public static function get_device_info($cpe_mac){

    $count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);
    $c_devices   = $count_device['Count_of_devices'];
    $c_active    = $count_device['Count_of_active'];
    $c_inactive  = $count_device['Count_of_inactive'];
    $c_offline   = $count_device['Count_of_offline'];

}
```

When I call that function:  `$devices = get_device_info($cpe_mac);`

I only have access to 1 variable which is `$devices`.

I won't have access to all my `5` variables in that function.

- $count_device
- $c_devices
- $c_active
- $c_inactive
- $c_offline

I've found [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php), but that is not really what I am looking for.

---

## Questions

How would one go about and implement this?

How do I move a block of code and include it back?

Should I start look into PHP's require/include?

Comment: Why do you need to set all these variables, can't you just use the array? Seems a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this all the time, particularly to use the same header/footer across the site. Simply place this line in the document in which you want to require the code.

```
<?php require_once('php/code_block_one.php'); ?>
```

If you want to call the same block of code multiple times in a single page, change `require_once` to `require`.

Comment: This will only run the code once. If you call this twice, it won't run anymore. Don't use `require_once`. Use `require` instead.

Comment: It is also poor code structure if you put every snippet in a separate file. The files will easily get messed up.

Comment: You commented before I could post my edit, and although I can't think of an instance in which functions or duplicate variable declarations would need to be required twice in a document, I've updated the answer to account for this.

Comment: It is actually very probable. For example, you may run this code in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap everything in a DeviceInfo class then just use the properties on that class.

```
class DeviceInfo 
{
    public $c_devices;
    public $c_active;
    public $c_inactive;
    public $c_offline;

    public function __construct($cpe_mac) {

        $count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);

        $this->c_devices   = $count_device['Count_of_devices'];
        $this->c_active    = $count_device['Count_of_active'];
        $this->c_inactive  = $count_device['Count_of_inactive'];
        $this->c_offline   = $count_device['Count_of_offline'];
    }
}
```

Have the Class in its own file called DeviceInfo.php, then where you need it just

```
include_once("DeviceInfo.php");
```

at the top of the file and create a new instance of that class. (I use include_once to make sure the DeviceInfo class isn't redefined if its already been defined)

```
$deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo($cpe_mac);
```

You can access the values by accessing the properties like this.

```
$deviceInfo->c_devices;
```

This way you get code completion for the values (depending on your IDE) and don't have to rely on remembering the array key names when you actually want to use that info in your code.

if You want to take it a step further, you can even add getter functions to this class, so if in the future you need to change how these values are calculated or fetched without changing the API its a lot simpler. That would look something like this:

```
class DeviceInfo 
{
    protected $c_devices;
    protected $c_active;
    protected $c_inactive;
    protected $c_offline;

    public function get_c_devices() {
        return $this->c_devices;
    }

    public function get_c_active() {
        return $this->c_active;
    }

    public function get_c_inactive() {
        return $this->c_inactive;
    }

    public function get_c_offline() {
        return $this->c_offline;
    }

    public function __construct($cpe_mac) {

        $count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);

        $this->c_devices   = $count_device['Count_of_devices'];
        $this->c_active    = $count_device['Count_of_active'];
        $this->c_inactive  = $count_device['Count_of_inactive'];
        $this->c_offline   = $count_device['Count_of_offline'];
    }
}
```

The only difference here is that now to get the values you'd call the functions instead of directly accessing the properties like so:

```
$deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo($cpe_mac);
$deviceInfo->get_c_devices(); // returns devices
```

For an example this simple, the extra code might not be worth it, but this does make it easier to update this code in the future without breaking all the points that these functions are called in the rest of your application.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change any of the variables on your page and you're potentially thinking about using a global function you could:

```
function get_device_info($cpe_mac)
{
    $count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);

    return [
        'c_devices'  => $count_device['Count_of_devices'],
        'c_active'   => $count_device['Count_of_active'],
        'c_inactive' => $count_device['Count_of_inactive'],
        'c_offline'  => $count_device['Count_of_offline'],
    ];

}
```

Then you would call:

```
extract(get_device_info($someVar));
```

and you would have access to:

```
$c_devices;
$c_active;
$c_inactive;
$c_offline;
```

Like you always have done

Please note I'm not saying this is a better answer than the others provided, I'm just saying it's an alternative.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like to add, that if he is willed to change his variables, all he need to change is replace the `extract(get_device_info($someVar));` with `$info = get_device_info($someVar);` and use `$info['c_devices']`, `$info['c_active']` (...) instead of `$c_devices`, `$c_active` (...)

Comment: This is a great solution if you don't want to change much existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Use pass-by-reference.

```
public static function 
get_device_info($cpe_mac, &$count_device, &$c_devices, &$c_active, &$c_inactive, &$c_offline){

    $count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);
    $c_devices   = $count_device['Count_of_devices'];
    $c_active    = $count_device['Count_of_active'];
    $c_inactive  = $count_device['Count_of_inactive'];
    $c_offline   = $count_device['Count_of_offline'];

}

// now to call this function...
Clazz::get_device_info("cpe_mac", $count_device, $c_devices, $c_active, $c_inactive, $c_offline);
var_dump($count_device, $c_devices, $c_active, $c_inactive, $c_offline);
// they output useful data!
```

Also, depending on your use case, if your PHP code isn't deployed from source to the server directly (e.g. if you released packaged phars, etc.), you may want to use `cpp` (the C preprocessor) to preprocess your files.

Answer (score 1):

```
//METHOD 1
public static $c_devices = null;
public static $c_active = null;
public static $c_inactive = null;
public static $c_offline = null;

public static function get_device_info($cpe_mac){

    $count_device = VSE::count_device($cpe_mac);
    self::$c_devices   = $count_device['Count_of_devices'];
    self::$c_active    = $count_device['Count_of_active'];
    self::$c_inactive  = $count_device['Count_of_inactive'];
    self::$c_offline   = $count_device['Count_of_offline'];

}

ClassName::$c_devices;
ClassName::$c_active;
ClassName::$c_inactive;
ClassName::$c_offline;




//METHOD 2
public static $cpe_mac = null;

public static function get_device_info($key){
    $count_device = VSE::count_device(self::$cpe_mac);
    return $count_device[$key];

}

ClassName::$cpe_mac = $cpe_mac;
ClassName::get_device_info('Count_of_devices');
ClassName::get_device_info('Count_of_active');
ClassName::get_device_info('Count_of_inactive');
ClassName::get_device_info('Count_of_offline');
```